# Remove object from array in List

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have a list of Customers, and each customer can have multiple orders, however I need to delete some of the orders from customers. If I loop through the list, I can find the Orders that I need to delete, but how do I actually delete them?

```
List<Customers>

public class Customers
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string NameFirst { get; set; }
    public Order[] Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Orders
{
    public string OrderMode { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Just a semantic remark: rename your class to `Customer`. A class represents a single object and should have a singular noun. Except for a collection-class (`Customers` would be a class representing a collection of customers). Same goes for your `Order`-class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `List<Order>` instead of an `Order[]` array:

```
public class Customers
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string NameFirst { get; set; }
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Then do the following:

```
customer.Orders.RemoveAll(x => x.OrderMode == "SomeOrder");
```

Answer (score 0):

use list collection instead of array (you can't remove item in array)

```
        YouList.Remove (Orders);
```

or
    YouList.RemoveAt(*index*)

Comment: Arrays do not have a `Remove`, nor a `RemoveAt` method.

Comment: yeah, but i forgot my info above